# Secure Storage in Maui - Android FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, storage, maui

When I am calling my Set method, I get FileNotFound Exception. I checked the documentation but did not see any specific implementations (beside two extra values in the manifest file)

Here is my code

```
public async Task SetAsync(string key, string value)
{
  await SecureStorage.SetAsync(key, value);
}
```

here is the androidmanifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <application android:allowBackup="false" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:exported="false" android:fullBackupContent="false" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

and here here is the exception

```
    [monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Security.SecurityCrypto.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.abc.mypp.test/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Security.SecurityCrypto.dll [External]
[AndroidKeysetManager] keyset not found, will generate a new one
[AndroidKeysetManager] java.io.FileNotFoundException: can't read keyset; the pref value __androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_key_keyset__ does not exist
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.SharedPrefKeysetReader.readPref(SharedPrefKeysetReader.java:71)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.SharedPrefKeysetReader.readEncrypted(SharedPrefKeysetReader.java:89)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.KeysetHandle.read(KeysetHandle.java:116)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.read(AndroidKeysetManager.java:311)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.readOrGenerateNewKeyset(AndroidKeysetManager.java:287)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.build(AndroidKeysetManager.java:238)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:155)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:120)
[AndroidKeysetManager] keyset not found, will generate a new one
[AndroidKeysetManager] java.io.FileNotFoundException: can't read keyset; the pref value __androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_value_keyset__ does not exist
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.SharedPrefKeysetReader.readPref(SharedPrefKeysetReader.java:71)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.SharedPrefKeysetReader.readEncrypted(SharedPrefKeysetReader.java:89)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.KeysetHandle.read(KeysetHandle.java:116)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.read(AndroidKeysetManager.java:311)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.readOrGenerateNewKeyset(AndroidKeysetManager.java:287)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.build(AndroidKeysetManager.java:238)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:160)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:120)
[EngineFactory] Provider GmsCore_OpenSSL not available
```

Comment: Can you show a little bit more of your code? Where is the ```SecureStorage``` object  coming from?

Comment: @ewerspej thank you for your reply. It is not an object, it is the static class of Microsoft.Maui.Storage some people use like SecureStorage.Default.Set(..) I tried it also but not working

Comment: In the documentation it says to use ```await SecureStorage.Default.SetAsync(...)```: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?tabs=android#use-secure-storage

Comment: @ewerspej I tried also with Default, same thing happen. I cannot Read either. Somehow I cannot use secureStorage library at all.

Comment: In the green tip box it says this: *"It's possible that an exception is thrown when calling GetAsync or SetAsync. This can be caused by a device not supporting secure storage, encryption keys changing, or corruption of data. it's best to handle this by removing and adding the setting back if possible."* Did you already try uninstalling the app, clean your build environment (delete bin and obj folders) and do a new deployment after rebuilding?

Comment: @ewerspej unfortunately it is the same. I am trying with a Xiaomi device. I have one plus too and will try with it.  Actually I put try-catch in SetAsync but it does not throw anything but it does not go further and I see the error in the log. So somehow it stucks there. By the way GetAsync started to work but of course the value is null. So now I have problem with writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I have created a sample to test the `Secure Storage` in the maui. I called the `await SecureStorage.SetAsync(key, value);` in the button's clicked event and run it on the simulator android 11, android 12 and physical device XiaoMi 6X android 9.

All of them worked correct, the key and value have been written into the device. So there may be two causes.

1. Special device: the issue appears on special devices, you can try to run the project on the other device or the simulators.
2. Some references' versions: I created the project on the visual studio 17.4 preview 2.1, you can upgrade the visual studio and create a new project to test it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried now with my device One Plus 8 pro Android 12 and got the same error. I updated my VS 17.3.6 (I am not sure to install preview version). I created another project. I will try there. Maybe our project has a problem.

Comment: By the way, I tried with iOS simulator, it works without problem. I have not tested with an android emulator

Comment: I also tried it on the Redmi K50 Pro just now and it worked will, I can get the key and value. @ertan2002